# Where's this verdant ridge?

Tags: identify-this

1. Reverse image searching turned up nothing, as the log-in box possibly belied the original picture.
2. Any geographers here? What type of [ridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge) is this?

[image]

Comment: If you're using Firefox, try selecting Tools->Page Info, and then select "Media". The background image should be there

Comment: I've done a very similar process to what CSM above but with chrome - I was able to get something I could reverse image search an original: https://wallpapers.99px.ru/wallpapers/239467/ its described as "Sunset on the background of a mountain meadow" with no hint as a location. May be helpful to someone else without the log in box though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While not an exact location the original image is available on shutterstock: https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/sunset-mountains-landscape-carpathian-ukraine-579416353 which described the image as being from the Carpathian Mountains in ukraine.